# Operator difference $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $d_x$ in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Dirac's book there is a displacement operator, $d_x$, which I conceived to be the same as derivative operator. But apparently it is not. What is the difference? They lead to different relations to the momentum listed in equation $(149)$ of [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/Quantumhtml/node24.html) and $(217)$ of [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/Quantumhtml/node28.html).

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the links to understand the question.

Comment: Sorry for that, and sorry for asking so quickly. I just found the answer in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)). I will type it all up tonight! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The displacement operator shifts the wave function A(x) to A(x+dx)

Comment: I think that is the translation operator which is different from Dirac's definition on displacement operator.